# Difference between Experimental Preprocessing layers and normal preprocessing layers in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
import tensorflow.keras.layers as tfl
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import RandomFlip, RandomRotation
```

I am trying to figure out which I should use for Data Augmentation. In the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers), there is:

tf.keras.layers.RandomFlip and RandomRotation

Then we have in [tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/experimental/preprocessing) the same things, randomFlip and RandomRotation.

Which should I use? I've seen [guides](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/preprocessing_layers) that use both.

This is my current code:

```
def data_augmenter():
data_augmentation = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tfl.RandomFlip(),
    tfl.RandomRotation(0.2)
])
return data_augmentation
```

and this is a part of my model:

```
def ResNet50(image_shape = IMG_SIZE, data_augmentation=data_augmenter()):

input_shape = image_shape + (3,)

# Remove top layer in order to put mine with the correct classification labels, get weights for imageNet
base_model = tf.keras.applications.resnet_v2.ResNet50V2(input_shape=input_shape, include_top=False, weights='imagenet')

# Freeze base model
base_model.trainable = False

# Define input layer
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=input_shape)

# Apply Data Augmentation
x = data_augmentation(inputs)
```

I am a bit confused here..

Comment: I'm pretty sure these will be the same layers with two import paths for backwards compatibility. I would lean toward using the one in `preprocessing` because it is considered stable and will be part of all future Keras 2.x implementations.

Comment: You can click on "View Aliases" to see that they are literally the same.

Comment: @philosofool Gotcha, so my implementation as I have it right now should be okay. Using the tensorflow.keras.layers (tfl) and not the experimental one. How can I mark this comment as answer? This is my first post in stackoverflow haha

Comment: @xdurch0 Oh yeah, you're right! Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: I created an answer below after checking a mechanism to confirm equivalence. You should be able to accept that as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you find something in an `experimental` module and something in the same package by the same name, these will typically be aliases of one another. For the sake of backwards compatibility, they don't remove the experimental one (at least not for a few iterations.)

You should generally use the non-experimental one if it exists, since this is considered stable and should not be removed or changed later.

The following page shows Keras preprocessing exerimental. If it redirects to the preprocessing module, it's an alias. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/experimental/preprocessing